# Why does this basic select query throw exception in foxpro?

Tags: foxpro

My simplified query is as follows.

```
select CustomerName as custname from customers where custname='Hey'
```

It says `Column custname is not found`. How can I handle this?

In sql it does not throw any exception and accepts `custname` as a column.

(In fact my query is more like `select IIF(...,...,...) as name from customers where custname='Hey'` than the above one.)

Comment: is it working with `where CustomerName = 'Hey'`

Comment: `name` is a `pseudo column`. A pseudo column cannot be used in inserts or other operations

Comment: @Bala Interestingly I can use custname in `group by` clause.

Comment: Please do not edit the original query, How is the original field named (the one on the database)?

Comment: @ericpap As it is turkish, I changed the field names.

Comment: @ericpap This is my original query. `select IIF(FPOLDOVTiP=0,99,FPOLDOVTiP) AS doviz from pol where doviz =99`

Comment: @sendar you are showing a different query now! also a different table! please be more clear in what do you need help with!

Comment: You can't do that! please see my edit answer!

Comment: @ericpap no, all the queries throws exception. When my original wury throwed exception I simplified it and still throwed exception.

Comment: Can one of the downvotes tell the reason? Off-topic? Or my problem  does not exist in foxpro?

Comment: The WHERE clause operates on the original tables. GROUP BY and HAVING operate on intermediate results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change the column name. In many languages the "name" keyword is reserved

**Edit**

With the new query, try this:

```
select IIF(FPOLDOVTiP=0,99,FPOLDOVTiP) AS doviz from pol where IIF(FPOLDOVTiP=0,99,FPOLDOVTiP)=99
```

You can't use calculated fields on where clause.

Comment: You are right. Looks like name is a reserved word http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xztfc506%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: ok worked this time, thanks. Will this have a performance effect? Calculating twice?

Comment: Yes but the most performace effect will be to use a where on a calculated field. You can't index that search so it will have a perfomance impact for large tables. In that case You should consider change your table structure or the way you are saving data to avoid using calculated fields.